# Are there any algorithms or methods to compute Landau function $g(n)$?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, algorithms

The details about Landau function can be found in [A000793](http://oeis.org/A000793).

Maybe there is some methods in [A000793](http://oeis.org/A000793), but I don't understand what it says. If possible, can someone illustrate the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I considered Michael Somos' pari script and added some comments :

```
{  a(n) = 
   local(m, t, j, u); 
   if (n < 2, 
       n >= 0, \\the result 0 or 1
   \\else
       m = ceil( n/exp(1) ); 
       t = ceil( (n/m)^m ); 
       j=1;                  \\init of result
       for (i=2, t, 
           u = factor(i);    \\returns [p1,a1],[p2,a2],...,[pm,am] if i=p1^a1 p2^a2...pm^am
           u = sum( k=1, matsize(u)[1], u[k, 1]^u[k, 2]); \\sum k=1 to m of pk^ak
           if (u <= n, j=i)  \\if the sum is not larger than n memorize i
       ); 
       j   \\the result
   )
}
```

Note that pari/gp is [free](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html) and rather convenient for tests !

This requires quite some factorizations. The [referenced paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2160) by Deleglise, Jean-Louis Nicolas and Paul Zimmermann 'Landau's function for one million billions' should be more interesting for large values.

Comment: Pari/GP rather uses `\\ ` for comments.

Comment: Thanks to notice @ccorn.

Comment: The referenced paper gives hints with regard to the correctness of Michael Somos's approach. Thanks for that link. Upvoted.

Comment: Thanks again @ccorn ! Let's add that Jean-Louis Nicolas proposes Maple code for $g(n)$'s evaluation at his [homepage](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/landaug.html) that could be useful too.

Comment: Glad it helped @JiabinHe!